# Postgresql's json_each()/jsonb_each() equivalent in MySQL 5.7.*?

Tags: mysql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, mysql-5.7

Is there any `json_each()`/`jsonb_each()` equivalent in MySQL 5.7.*?

According to the [article](https://blogs.oracle.com/svetasmirnova/entry/mysql_and_postgresql_json_functions) I found: "Not supported, cannot be implemented using UDFs only".

I want to port the following view to MySQL, however I do not see any function available that would allow me to convert what's in json to table rows. All the functions that I found can only be used in projection (like `JSON_KEYS`, `JSON_EXTRACT`, etc.) and not in join part.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_team_result AS
  SELECT my_column1 a,
    j.key::integer b,
    to_json(j.value->'c')::text::bigint c,
    to_json(j.value->'d')::text::bigint d
  FROM my_table, jsonb_each(my_json_column) j;
```

If there is nothing available, how can it be implemented?

Comment: OFF: from the same link: *json_array_length(json) | Not supported, planned as bug*. Good to see that MySQL lives up to its legacy /OFF

Comment: Yes, that given article is right, MySQL has no support of set-returning functions whatsoever. Procedures could, however you cannot use those in JOINs. LATERAL support is off the table too.